# Show last input on a LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Here is my question, how can I get the `topic_id = 27` inside the `cat_id = 2` ?

Also the other "new" topic like `ID = 24`

Thanks for all, and sorry for my not-knowledge and my english :-)

[image: Result in HTML]
[image: ][DataBase]]
[image: Code]

```
$cat = $bdd->prepare('SELECT  * from categories LEFT JOIN topics on topic_cat = cat_id group by cat_id limit 5 ');
$cat_show_list = $cat->execute();



echo '<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>5 Dernières catégories</th>
        <th>Dernier topic</th>
    </tr>';

while ($cat_show_list = $cat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ORI_FIRST)){
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td class="#">';
echo '<h4><a href="category.php?id='. $cat_show_list['cat_id'].'">'. $cat_show_list['cat_name'].'</a></h4>'.'';
echo '<a> '.$cat_show_list['cat_description'] . '</a>';
echo '</td>';
echo '<td>'.  $cat_show_list['topic_subject'];
echo '</tr>';

}
$cat->closeCursor();
```

Comment: post your code as actual code, please, not as screnshot.

Comment: Yes, sorry for this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL query was

```
SELECT
    categories.*,
    (SELECT topics.topic_subject
     FROM topics
     WHERE topics.topic_cat = categories.cat_id
     ORDER BY topics.topic_date DESC
     LIMIT 1) AS category_last_subject
FROM 
    categories
ORDER BY 
    categories.cat_id DESC
LIMIT 5
```